# mat-select detect Panel position

Tags: javascript, css, angular, angular-material

I want to detect the position of the panel, when it is opened, so I can apply the appropriate changes on the mat-select.

For example here:
[image] the Panel is on **Top** of the mat-select

And here : [image] the Panel is on the **Bottom** of the mat-select.

is there any property provided in the Panel or the MatSelect that provides that ?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution,
in the className of the offsetParent we can find a class `mat-mdc-select-panel-above`

it is accessible while doing
`this.select.panel.nativeElement.offsetParent.className` select is an instance of the `MatSelect` from
`import { MatSelect } from "@angular/material/select";`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).